# Limit of over the real line

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying to find $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \biggl(\frac{x + \log9}{x - \log9} \biggr)^x $$

While I know the methods for getting limits of various indeterminate forms like like $\frac{0}{0}, \frac{\infty}{\infty},1^\infty,0\times0,\infty \times \infty$ this appears to be $\bigl(\frac{\infty}{\infty}\bigr)^\infty$.

How to convert it to some other indeterminate form whose limit can be found by standard methods.

Comment: It is of type $1^\infty$.

Comment: are we doing $\biggl( \frac{1 + \frac{\log9}{x}}{1 - \frac{\log9}{x}} \biggr)$?

Comment: Yes, the limit of the fraction is $1$.

Comment: I will take the limit of the log of that function and use L'Hospital rule.

Comment: @ArpitYadav Huh?

Comment: $0\times0$ is not indeterminate form.

Comment: If you want systematic computation of a wide class of limits, asymptotic expansions is what you need. For some motivation of the technique see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2131837/21820) and for some examples see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2122660/21820) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/809591/21820) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1536437/21820).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$f(x) = \left( \frac{x+\log 9}{x-\log 9} \right)^x.$$ We want to compute $\lim_{x\to\infty} \log f(x)$, and then exponentiate the result.
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} x \log \frac{x+\log 9}{x-\log 9} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log \frac{x+\log 9}{x-\log 9}}{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(2\log 9) x^2}{x^2 - \log^2 9} = 2\log 9,
$$
where the second equality follows from L'Hospital Rule. The final answer should be $e^{2\log 9} = 81$.

Answer (score 4):

By a shift of the variable

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \biggl(\frac{x + \log9}{x - \log9} \biggr)^x =\lim_{y \to \infty} \biggl(\frac{y +2 \log9}{y} \biggr)^{y+\log 9} =\lim_{y \to \infty} \biggl(1+\frac{2 \log9}{y} \biggr)^y\biggl(1+\frac{2 \log9}{y} \biggr)^{\log 9}.$$

The first factor is recognized as a case of the exponential function,

$$\lim_{y \to \infty} \biggl(1+\frac{2 \log9}{y} \biggr)^y=\lim_{z \to \infty} \biggl(1+\frac1z \biggr)^{z\,2 \log9}=e^{2\log 9}=\color{green}{81}$$ while the second factor tends to $1$.

Comment: Without L'Hospital.

Answer (score 1):

this limit in the ${ 1 }^{ \infty  }$ form so
$$\lim _{ x\to \infty  } \left( \frac { x+\log  9 }{ x-\log  9 }  \right) ^{ x }=\lim _{ x\to \infty  } \left( 1+\frac { 2\log  9 }{ x-\log  9 }  \right) ^{ x }=\lim _{ x\to \infty  }{ \left[ \left( 1+\frac { 2\log  9 }{ x-\log  9 }  \right) ^{ \frac { x-\log  9 }{ 2\log  9 }  } \right]  } ^{ \frac { 2\log  9 }{ x-\log  9 } x }=\\ =\lim _{ x\to \infty  }{ e } ^{ \frac { 2\log  9 }{ x-\log  9 } x }={ e }^{ 2\log  9 }=81$$

Comment: @Adayah Usually easy to do by squeeze theorem and/or Bernoulli's inequalities.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I deleted my comment when I noticed more mistakes so the author has time to correct them. In particular, the result is wrong.

Comment: @Adayah Yes.  It may help to observe that
$$\left(1+\frac a{x-b}\right)^x\sim_\infty\left(1+\frac ax\right)^x$$

Comment: @Adayah,where is the mistake,i don't understand

Comment: The $x$ in the exponent disappeared.

Comment: @haqnatural Aherm, the limit is probably $e^{2\log9}=81$ wink wink

Comment: @haqnatural Well, you haven't corrected it yet, so perhaps I'll be more explicit.  $$x\ne\frac{x-\log9}{2\log9}\frac{2\log9}{x-\log9}$$That is, you seem to be missing something by the third limit.

Comment: Oh, sorry, guys, i was blind,I missed $x$,adn didn't see this comments,thank you

Answer (score 0):

Write  $$\biggl(\frac{x + \log9}{x - \log9} \biggr)^x =e^{x\ln{(\frac{x + \log9}{x - \log9})}}$$
I have not checked if the limit can be solved with this form but this is a form you know and you can try working with it.

If you want you can solve the limit $$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}\ln{(\frac{x + \log9}{x - \log9})}$$

$P.S:$

This answer was downvoted before some minutes but i do not understand why,because the O.P did not ask  for his limit to be solved completely.