# Find $\lim_{{x \to 0}} \frac{{2x \ln(1 + x) + x^3}}{{\sqrt{1 - e^{-(x^{4})}}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

$$\lim_{{x \to 0}} \frac{{2x \ln(1 + x) + x^3}}{{\sqrt{1 - e^{-(x^{4})}}}}$$

I want to find easy solution of this limit, because I know that it's possible to make some uses of L'Hôpital's rule and find the limit (which will be $2$), but it would cost a lot of time. But I wonder if there is easy solution (e.g making some changes to task and then easily find limit by L'Hôpital's rule).

I've tried to put $x$ and $x^3$ out of brackets, made some transformations of $\sqrt{1 - e^{-(x^{4})}}$, and some other attempts, but nothing worked out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about power series?

Comment: @CheeHan Honestly I don't know how to use power series there

Comment: I noticed that you accepted an answer that uses power series, but fails to do it rigorously. Please see "[Is it okay to "ignore" small numbers in limits where $x$ approaches infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2504081/is-it-okay-to-ignore-small-numbers-in-limits-where-x-approaches-infinity)" for the proper approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can write down the following power series expansion near $x = 0$ (i.e., Maclaurin series):
\begin{align*} 
\ln(1 + x) & = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n - 1}x^n}{n} = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \dots \\ 
e^{-x^4} & = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{4n}}{n!} = 1 - x^4 + \frac{x^8}{2!} - \frac{x^{12}}{3!} + \dots.  
\end{align*}
It follows that
\begin{align*} 
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x\ln(1 + x) + x^3}{\sqrt{1 - e^{-x^4}}} & = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x\left(x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \dots\right) + x^3}{\sqrt{x^4 - \frac{x^8}{2!} + \frac{x^{12}}{6!} - \dots}} \\ 
& = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x\left(x + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \dots\right)}{x^2\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^4}{2!} + \frac{x^8}{3!} - \dots}}. 
\end{align*}
Can you finish the problem from here?

Comment: I think yes. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$. Then,
$$\frac{2x\ln(1+x) + x^3}{\sqrt{1 - e^{-x^4}}} = \frac{2x\ln(1+x) + x^3}{\sqrt{1 - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{4n}}{n!}}} = \frac{2x\ln(1+x) + x^3}{\sqrt{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{4n}}{n!}}} = \frac{2x\ln(1+x) + x^3}{x^2\sqrt{ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{4n}}{(n+1)!}}}.$$

Note that $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{4n}}{(n+1)!}} = 1$. Thus, we can write
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x\ln(1+x) + x^3}{\sqrt{1 - e^{-x^4}}} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x\ln(1+x) + x^3}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0} 2\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} + x.$$

Now, we can use L'Hôpital's rule to get
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x\ln(1+x) + x^3}{\sqrt{1 - e^{-x^4}}} =\lim_{x\to 0} 2\frac{\frac{1}{1+x}}{1} + x = 2$$.

Or did I miss something?

Comment: I don't know if after noting that $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{4n}}{(n+1)!}} = 1$ we can just put $1$ in the problem. But if it's true (i hope someone will confirm that), you have a good solution!

Comment: If you have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$ and  $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = b$, and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \cdot b_n= a \cdot b$.

Comment: OK it's true but why does $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{4n}}{(n+1)!}} = 1$? Why $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} = 1?$

Comment: Oh, no. The first element in the series (for n = 0) is 1. All other elements are converging to zero. Note also that 0! = 1.

Comment: I think I understood. Thank you very much for your answers.